# Load Google Apps, while keeping my domain name

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iframe, proxy

Basically, I am trying to redirect my own URL e.g. `apps.mydomain.com` to Google Apps. I would like to keep my domain name in the URL.

I tried using `iframe`, but it does not load Google in an iframe. It does load other websites. I also tried using htaccess and the `[P]` flag, but it says `index.html not found`.

`mod_rewrite` is enabled on my server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

The `[L]` redirect seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to this. Google have enabled `X-Frame-Options: Deny` which prevents this scenario for security reasons.

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options